# Can't install enterprise app on iPad Air

Tags: ios, ipad, ipa, bitrise

I have an enterprise account and I'm using s3 to publish the app. Also, using Bitrise for CI.

We encountered a weird situation that two brand new iPads air are unable to use either of the distribution solutions.

They have this screen:
[image]

Then this:
[image]

But never this:
[image]

This link does work for iPhones.

Comment: Did you check the iOS Device Logs for errors related to the install? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2319/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013778-CH1-TPRO

Comment: Also, you're trying from Safari and from non private/incognito tab, right?